# Doctrine Error: syntax error or access violation: 10649

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

I have two classes Product and Manager, here is the code for each class (in Product I will put just related code):

Code for Product Entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
* @ORM\Table(name="products")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
*/
class Product {
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Manager", mappedBy="products")
  **/
  private $manager;
}
```

And here is the code for Manager Entity

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
* @ORM\Table(name="shipping_methods")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Manager {

  /**
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
  protected $id;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=8, scale=2, options={"default" = 0})
  */
  protected $percentage;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
  */
  protected $name;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
  */
  protected $quantity;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
  */
  protected $where;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
  */
  protected $flag;

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="shipping")
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="manager_methods")
  **/
  protected $products;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set percentage
     *
     * @param string $percentage
     * @return Manager
     */
    public function setPercentage($percentage)
    {
        $this->percentage = $percentage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get percentage
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPercentage()
    {
        return $this->percentage;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Manager
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     * @return Manager
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set where
     *
     * @param string $where
     * @return Manager
     */
    public function setWhere($where)
    {
        $this->where = $where;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get where
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getWhere()
    {
        return $this->where;
    }

    /**
     * Set flag
     *
     * @param string $flag
     * @return Manager
     */
    public function setFlag($flag)
    {
        $this->flag = $flag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get flag
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFlag()
    {
        return $this->flag;
    }

    /**
     * Add products
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Product $products
     * @return Manager
     */
    public function addProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\Product $products)
    {
        $this->products[] = $products;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove products
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Product $products
     */
    public function removeProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\Product $products)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($products);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
```

Into my controller I have a function where I am creating a Manager Entity and a Product, first I create a Manager object and later I create a Product object to link them. But there is a problem that I haven't see since yesterday when I try to insert the Manager object. I will paste here the error that gives me Symfony and the code where I obtain the error.

Code where I obtain the error:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$shipping = new Manager();
$shipping->setPercentage(1);
$shipping->setName("Name");
$shipping->setQuantity(1);
$shipping->setFlag("flag");
$shipping->setWhere("where");
$em->persist($shipping);
$em->flush();
```

And here is the error from Symfony:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO shipping_methods (percentage, name, quantity, where, flag) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [1, "Name", 1, "where", "flag"]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where, flag) VALUES ('1', 'Name', 1, 'where', 'flag')' at line 1
```

If someone could help me I will be very very grateful due to that I am really stuck with this problem... Thanks!

Comment: Notice how the 1064 points exactly to the error location.  (Sometimes the naughty word/punctuation is before the indicated location; this time it was at the location.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` is a reserved word. You should [quote](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words) or rename your column.
Try this (pay attention to backticks):

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="`where`", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
*/
protected $where;
```

Comment: I didn't know that... Thanks you so much, you saved me more wasted time... Thanks again